# Is there any similar jtrac ticketing system?

Tags: java, web-applications, workflow, jbpm

Is there any free java ticketing system like jtrac with workflow feature? jira is not free though.

Answer (score 1):

None that I know about (and I may not be the only one to not know an [alternative to JTrac](http://ostatic.com/j-trac/alternatives/1)).
The closest -- but ***non-java*** -- alternative, would be [MantisBT](http://www.mantisbt.org/). It does have, for instance, a [Mylyn connector](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mylyn-mantis/develop), which can come in handy when you have to link your ticketing to an IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/).